# Showing contents of a word document file in a textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a asp.net web page which has a textarea control on it.
In this control, I need to show contents of a word document file which is sitting on the server.
Can someone please help me with the  C# code ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

http://www.programmerfish.com/quick-tutorial-how-to-read-microsoft-word-file-in-c/

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b6f75379-840c-4745-a76c-04d43694333b/read-any-document-like-.aspx